# Prevent horizontal scroll for jQuery show() transition

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

I'm using jQuery to load a div from a target page and replace an existing div with the newly loaded content. To make this look a bit better I have added a jQuery transition effect to 'slide' then existing content off to the left and 'slide' the new content on from the right.

JS Extract:

```
...
$('#content-slider').hide('drop', {}, 2000, function() {
    ('#content-slider').load(pageurl + '?rel=tab  #content-slider');
    $('#content-slider').show('drop', {direction:'right'}, 2000);
});
...
```

The problem is that the newly loaded div that is being animated by 'sliding' in from the right causes the div to have an 'animated' horizontal scroll bar. As the div slides into place the scroll bar decreases until it finally disappears as the new div content settles in place.

I need to prevent that horizontal scroll bar appearing. The obvious choice was simply to go for `overflow-x: hidden;` but that doesn't stop the effect.

Comment: could you maybe add a fiddle?

Comment: Are you ending up with 2 `#content-slider` `divs`? That might cause things to act strange.

Comment: Are you setting the `overflow: hidden` on the parent container of `#content-slider`?

Comment: @Jack Well noticed. It appears I am in fact ending up with 2 `#content-slider` `divs`. One inside the other. Suggestions for revising JS?

Comment: Rename one of them, can't have two elements with the same Id. It could bet hat your overflow property is applying to one but not the other.

Comment: Please provide [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) example.

Comment: @Jack I need the containers to stay the same on each page. instead I need to modify the jQuery statement to load the html inside the `#content-slider`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set to the parent of `#content-slider` a fixed width and `overflow: hidden`. If you don't want a fixed width you can also use [`max-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/max-width).

Answer (score 1):

have you tried

```
overflow: hidden !important;
```

Comment: I would try to avoid using "!important" if you can.

Comment: ...with `!important` being **temporary** so you can see if it's `overflow: hidden` that does the fix. It's best practice to avoid `!important`. CSS rules are applied based on the most specific selector.

Comment: I did try `!important` just to see if anything was _interfering_ but that didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Give `#content-slider` a fixed width and `overflow: hidden`. If you don't want a fixed width you can also use [`max-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/max-width). If this doesn't what you want, set both CSS-styles to the parent of `#content-slider`.

Comment: @da_re Adding a parent div and styling that did the trick. If you want to put that as an answer Ill mark it as correct.

Comment: Late to comment but add width:100% with overflow on the parent